# Form in React and TypeScript with DRY handle of change

Tags: reactjs, forms, typescript, dry

I looking for best way manage state of form in React with TypeScript. My simple form have two values: `login` and `password` fields. I implement `IState` interface for form state and DRY `handleChange` method for store new value in state without recreating function in each `render()` execution.

```
interface IState {
  login: string;
  password: string;
}

class LoginForm extends React.Component<{}, IState> {
  public state = {
    login: "",
    password: "",
  };

  public render() {
    const { login, password } = this.state;
    return (
      <form>
        <input name="login" value={login} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <input name="password" value={password} onChange={this.handleChange} type="password"/>
      </form>
    );
  }

  private handleChange = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = e.currentTarget;
    const n = name as keyof IState;
    // @ts-ignore
    this.setState({
      [n]: value,
    });
  }
}
```

I use native HTML's `name` attribute for store field name. `n` variable will have only `login` or `password` value. Any other value is impossible. Can I tell TypeScript the `n` variable is `"login" | "password"` literals type? TypeScript regard `n` as `string` type variable even I use:

```
const n = name as keyof IState;
```

or

```
const n = name as "login" | "password";
```

Then, when I remove `// @ts-ignore` I get error:

```
Type error: Argument of type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IState | Pick<IState, "login" | "password"> | ((prevState: Readonly<IState>, props: Readonly<IProps>) => IState | Pick<IState, "login" | "password"> | null) | null'.
Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<IState, "login" | "password">': login, password  TS2345
```

but no error when I hardcode:

```
const n = "login";
```

Any way to force `"login" | "password"` type to `n` variable? Or any other solution for DRY `handleChange` without optimization issues and pure TypeScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `Pick` to ensure that you're setting a key that has been defined in your `IState` interface.

[image: Pick - set state]

```
private handleChange = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = e.currentTarget;
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    } as Pick<IState, keyof IState>);
};
```

Or alternative you can use `Partial` which will make all your state keys optional.

```
class App extends React.Component<{}, Partial<IState>> {
    // ... rest of component
}
```

Comment: What is different than `} as any`?

Comment: The first one will error out if you don’t specify a key that has been defined. The 2nd one uses a partial which means it’s the same interface as IState but all of the keys are optional. This means you don’t need to type ? Next to all the keys. But overall partial won’t be any different to an any, use Pick.

Answer (score 2):

1.Declare your interface

```
interface IState {
  login: string;
  password: string;
}
```

2.Declare your state

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState<IState>()
```

3.Declare your onchange function

```
const onChange=(e: any): void => {
    const { name, value } = e.currentTarget;
    setMyState({ ...myState, [name]: value });
}
```

4.Declare your markup

```
<input name="login" type="text" onChange={onChange}/>
```

We are using the spread function to maintain and update the state Note that you need to name the markup element with the "name" attribute and it should correspond with your interface attribute

[Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

[React naming elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs)